# Class App\Http\Controllers\UserController Does Not Exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

Having the issue when loading the route /users or /user/add and being return an error of;

> ReflectionException in Route.php line 280: Class
>   App\Http\Controllers\App\Controllers\UserController does not exist

The UserController does exist and it is not in a folder within my controllers folder.

My route file;

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/route/selector', 'PagesController@selectRoute');

    // Admin Only //
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'isAdmin'], function(){
        Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');

        Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index');
        Route::get('/user/add', 'UserController@getAdd');
        Route::post('/user/add', 'UserController@postAdd');
        Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@getEdit');
        Route::post('/user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@postEdit');
        Route::get('/user/delete/{id}', 'UserController@delete');
    });
});
```

My UserController;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use App\UserTypes;

use Auth;
use Hashids;
use Redirect;
use Request;
use Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $users = User::get();
        return view('users.index', compact('users'));
    }

    public function getAdd(){
        $user_type = UserTypes::pluck('user_type', 'id');
        return view('users.add', compact('user_type'));
    }

    public function postAdd(){
        $input = Request::all();
        $password = str_random(8);
        User::create(
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($password),
            'first_name' => $input['first_name'],
            'surname' => $input['surname'],
            'phone_number' => $input['phone_number'],
            'user_type' => $input['user_type'],
        );

        return Redirect::action('UserController@index');
    }

    public function getEdit($id){

    }

    public function postEdit($id){

    }

    public function delete($id){
        User::find(current(Hashids::decode($id)))->delete();
        return Redirect::action('UserController@index');
    }

}
```

**When I remove the User::create(); part the error disappears, will it have something to do with this?**

Comment: Try to run `composer dumpauto` command.

Comment: What is the path of your `UserController`? As you are using `namespace App\Http\Controllers` it has to be inside `app/Http/Controllers` directory

Comment: Thanks both, composer dumpauto did not make any differences. Also the controller is within the app/Http/Controllers directory

Comment: When I remove the User::create(); part the error dissapears, will it have something to do with this?

Comment: you are missing the use of the class at the top .

Answer (score 54):

Laravel 8.x update has a different way of using routes.

Previously it was:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
```

Now it has changed to

```
Route::get('/',[PagesController::class, 'index']);
```

**Note: don't forget to import (use) your controller in the routes(web.php) file at the top. Like:**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;
```

Comment: That happened to me when me did `save movement` controller file (under `refactor`  option) to a folder. I did what @Maz341 said but additionally have corrected namespace  in MyController class file, removed prefix(one's folder) in `[prefix\MyController::class, '...']` and reimported Controller parent. And relaunched the server . Now its all ok

Comment: Thanks man... I came back from Laravel 5. Lot of things changed.

Comment: In my case, I was using lower case `a` in `use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;`. Just convert in to upper case

Answer (score 5):

Replace this code

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'isAdmin'], function(){
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');

    Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index');
    Route::get('/user/add', 'UserController@getAdd');
    Route::post('/user/add', 'UserController@postAdd');
    Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@getEdit');
    Route::post('/user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@postEdit');
    Route::get('/user/delete/{id}', 'UserController@delete');
});
```

with this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'isAdmin'], function(){
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::group(['namespace' => YOUR_NAMESPACE], function(){
        Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index');
        Route::get('/user/add', 'UserController@getAdd');
        Route::post('/user/add', 'UserController@postAdd');
        Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@getEdit');
        Route::post('/user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@postEdit');
        Route::get('/user/delete/{id}', 'UserController@delete');
    });
});
```

& in your `UserController` you should correct your `namespace` also

e.g your `UserController` resides in `app/Controllers` directory then your `UserController` will be like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use App\UserTypes;

use Auth;
use Hashids;
use Redirect;
use Request;
use Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $users = User::get();
        return view('users.index', compact('users'));
    }

    public function getAdd(){
        $user_type = UserTypes::pluck('user_type', 'id');
        return view('users.add', compact('user_type'));
    }

    public function postAdd(){
        $input = Request::all();
        $password = str_random(8);
        User::create(
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($password),
            'first_name' => $input['first_name'],
            'surname' => $input['surname'],
            'phone_number' => $input['phone_number'],
            'user_type' => $input['user_type'],
        );

        return Redirect::action('UserController@index');
    }

    public function getEdit($id){

    }

    public function postEdit($id){

    }

    public function delete($id){
        User::find(current(Hashids::decode($id)))->delete();
        return Redirect::action('UserController@index');
    }

}
```

& your route will be like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/route/selector', 'PagesController@selectRoute');

    // Admin Only //
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'isAdmin'], function(){
        Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
        Route::group(['namespace' => '\App\Controllers'], function(){
            Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index');
            Route::get('/user/add', 'UserController@getAdd');
            Route::post('/user/add', 'UserController@postAdd');
            Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@getEdit');
            Route::post('/user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@postEdit');
            Route::get('/user/delete/{id}', 'UserController@delete');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: My User Controller resides in app/Http/Controllers not app/Controllers would this make a difference? I have built many laravel apps before and this has never been an issue.

Comment: When I remove the User::create(); part the error disappears, will it have something to do with this?

Comment: ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Controllers\UserController does not exist

Comment: @KieranHeadley Your route namespace is incorrect. If I see your `route service provide` & `route` then I could have find the solution. For temporary you can use my solution of route part & replace this text `Route::group(['namespace' => '\App\Controllers'], function(){` with this `Route::group(['namespace' => '\App\Http\Controllers'], function(){`

Comment: My route namespace is set to 'App\Http\Controllers' in /app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

Answer (score 3):

The `create` method is missing the array brackets.

```
User::create([
    'email' => $input['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($password),
    'first_name' => $input['first_name'],
    'surname' => $input['surname'],
    'phone_number' => $input['phone_number'],
    'user_type' => $input['user_type'],
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Laravel 8 has updated the route format. The above route will only be for Laravel 8 or higher. If your Laravel version is less than 8 try using:

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 8 updated the Route format, please try the updated format on controllers routes.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to add this line to your controller

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

If this is not present in your controller your controller is not able to extend the features of the main Laravel controller prototypes

Answer (score 2):

be sure to type correctly `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` as my mistaken was with incorrect typing of `use App\Http\Controller\Controller;`

just instead of `controllers/controller` I mistakenly missed **s** at the end of `controllers/controller` and I typed controller/controller which was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

this happen because you are missing `Controller` class which has extends for it and others reasons depended on your actions.

to solve this problem you need to use `Controller` class in your `UserController`.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

or
you can easily avoiding that be type on the console

```
php artisan make:controller UserController
```

that will solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You are getting 2 errors, the last one gets shown on the top of the page, and that error is that the controller does not exist. The reason why you are seeing that error is because the Model::create() method expects an array of attributes, whilst you are calling it with separate arguments instead.

**Try:**

```
$user = User::create([
    'email' => $input['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($password),
    'first_name' => $input['first_name'],
    'surname' => $input['surname'],
    'phone_number' => $input['phone_number'],
    'user_type' => $input['user_type'],
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::get('/', 'api\AppController@appInfo');
```

I created `AppController` in `controller/api` folder so this is my path. You need to give path till your controller.

Answer (score -1):

[DOCS Laravel 8.x controllers#resource-controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

On file routes/web.php

`use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;`
and then
`Route::resource('user',UserController::class);`

Answer (score -1):

in laravel 8 do the following
remove the comment from RouteServiceProvider.php
First of all Open RouteServiceProvider.php located at app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php

Now remove comment of following line.

protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

Answer (score -1):

The best solution for this problem is to open the file "Providers/RouteServiceProvider" and edit it. But, first, add it to the RouteServiceProvider class.

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

Next, in the boot() function.

```
$this->configureRateLimiting();

$this->routes(function () {
    Route::middleware('api')
        ->prefix('api')
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    Route::namespace($this->namespace)
        ->middleware('web')
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    Route::namespace($this->namespace)
        ->middleware('web')
        ->group(base_path('routes/dashboard.php'));
})
```