# Class App\Http\Controllers\StudentController does not exist in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

I am building a module called Student in Laravel.

I use the routes.php file inside the Student folder to write routes realted to student module..

When I use just `Route::get('/list', function () { return view('welcome');});` program working **fine without error**.

But when I am using `Route::get('/list', 'StudentController@list');` there is a error.

Error is,

> Class App\Http\Controllers\StudentController does not exist

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**Student Controller**

```
namespace App\Student\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function list(){
        echo "Hello"
    }
}
```

**Student Service Provider**

```
namespace App\Student;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class StudentServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @internal param Router $router
     */

    public function map()
    {
        Route::group([
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => 'students',
        ], function ($router) {
            require __DIR__ . '/routes.php';
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: try with this `Route::get('student/list', 'StudentController@list');`

Comment: Can you show the content of `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` and `routes.php` ?

Comment: @Kaspars It is just `Route::get('/list', 'StudentController@list');`  line in students/routes.php. I have not touched RouteServiceProvider file. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

Comment: Check this link out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63871723/5857099

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although laravel is magic at times, it only works if you stick the the default configuration and conventions.

You *can* place your controllers anywhere (heck, even load from a database and `eval` them) but you have to change the configuration accordingly.

I suspect you have the wrong namespace configured in [RouteServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L17). By default it is `App\Http\Controllers`.

## Changing default folder

If all your controllers will be in the same folder, change it to `App\Student\Controllers` and forget about it.

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // ...
    protected $namespace = 'App\Student\Controllers';
    // ...
}
```

## Multiple modules

If you want to have multiple modules, then change your RotueServiceProvider namespace config to `App` and in route files use `Student\Controllers\StudentController@list`

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // ...
    protected $namespace = 'App';
    // ...
}

Route::get('/list', 'Student\Controllers\StudentController@list');
```

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly fine. And I got another answer from another forum. It is just adding `protected $namespace = 'App\Student\Controllers';` to Student Service Provider page. It also worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

go to RouteServiceProvider.php 
and the changed the namespace to default

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

Answer (score 2):

it gives you that error because the controller couldn't find the class you are calling .. in the top of your controller add

```
use App\Student;
```

to make it work ..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it also. But same result.

Comment: oh my bad i thought the model was the missing .. updating my answer

Comment: No, still I haven't used models for this project. Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: the route couldn't find the controller .. have you tried `Route::get('/list', 'Student/Controllers/StudentController@list');` or `Route::get('/list', 'Controllers/StudentController@list');`

Comment: I can't move it to  HTTP folder because I must use this strcuture for this project. I tried `Route::get('/list', 'Student/Controllers/StudentController@list');` also. But same error. ? :-(

Answer (score 1):

You create controller in wrong location. 
Default Controller location is :

```
app/Http/Controllers
```

Comment: actually he may do that .. he had his own coding convention .. he had change its namespace as you can see .. what he's missing is the `use App\Student`

Comment: No, when you create modules you can create folder called 'controllers' under another folder and create controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is in wrong place. It should be inside `app/Http/Controllers/`.

You can make further folder Student inside `app/Http/Controllers/` and extending the main Controller to make your isolated module **Student**.

You file structure should like:

```
app[dir]
----Http[dir]
-------Controllers[dir]
----------Student[dir]
----------Controller.php[file]
```

Your Student Controller should look like,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Student;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class StudentController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

   ....
}
```

Comment: No, when you create modules you can create folder called 'controllers' under another folder and create controllers

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson I've used above approach for such situation. This may or mayn't acceptable for you.

Comment: when you working big projects you may have to create modules. Read more : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39846287/8246224

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your route by this:

```
 Route::get('/list', '\App\Student\Controllers\StudentController@list');
```

Hope it help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurs when you move a previously created **Controller** into another folder inside **Controllers** folder:

```
|Controllers
|Controller.php
|--|Setup [Folder]
    |MovedController.php
```

Just make sure the **namespace** is correct and import `Controller.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Setup;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```