# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\usercontroller] does not exist

Tags: class, target

My route file is:

[image]

and my usercontroll file is:

1.[image]

2. [image]

This only happen on live server but perfectly works on localhost.
Please give me solutions.
[Futuristicways.com](https://futuristicways.com)

Answer (score 0):

With the Laravel latest updates (8x and above) the routing is changed.

Previously it was

```
Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');
```

Now it has changed into

```
Route::get('/',[UserController::class, 'index']);
```

**And you must import UserController in your routes/web.php or routes/api.php(if you`re using api)

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
```

Refer the answer to this question [Class App\Http\Controllers\UserController Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321755/class-app-http-controllers-usercontroller-does-not-exist)